# ActivityViewController fails to share link on WhatsApp and Mail App?

Tags: ios, swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I used following code to share some url on WhatsApp and Mail.

```
 @objc func onclickOfShareButton(sender:UIButton){
        let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"https://myDomain/path/\(String(zoomLocation.index))")
        let shareAll = [myWebsite ?? []] as [Any]
        activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When i share with WhatsApp i cannot select contacts to whom i need to share. Some cases i cannot click on next button once selected contacts.

It is able to share sometime but if fails as well. Once app is closed and reopen it works 2-3 times.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: If it works sometimes, there must be a bug with the OS. Selecting WhatsApp contacts has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @ojassethi. Not sure. but if i push this code in new project it works! Using Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Issue with code was too many timer set to repeats: true. When i make them "false" it works fine.

```
self.counterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fetchCount), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Timer may trigger point to ActivityViewController to go away while sharing. Hope this help someone.